# Meaning of "bar top"

Tags: meaning

I found this part of a sentence:

> "bullets riddled the bar top, glasses shattered, bottles exploded."

What is the "top" of a bar?
I guess with 70% assurance that it's a bar counter, isn't it?

Comment: I understand that "bar top" isn't necessarily in a dictionary, so I can understand why this question was asked, but I saw little point in leaving it open, now that the O.P.'s suspicions have been confirmed. As an aside, dennylv, please try to put your question in your question, and not in your title. Also, tell us where you find these sentences; sometimes that information is critical. You can read more [here](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439).

Comment: May I say something? To non-native learners, and I'm one of them,it's really hard to decide what kind of language question is inappropriate to ask. Many of our difficulties in understanding or using English come from culture,history,life,tradition,etc. Not merely limited to grammar or syntax. To me, sometimes a maybe "easy word" in a native speaker's mind can be quite subtle or tricky,and I really hope you would understand that. I did consult dictionaries but I was not yet sure bar+top is simply the surface of a bar counter.Anyway, I'll try my best to make my questions neat and standardized.

Comment: BTW, what does "O.P." mean?

Comment: O.P. = Original Post (if referring to the question) or Original Poster (if referring to the person who asked it). As for appropriate questions to ask, ask whatever you need or want to ask. The more research you do first, and the more of that research you include in the question, the better the question will be received. The community enjoys helping those who are puzzled, but we don't necessarily want to be consulted before a dictionary or search engine. But, yes, it's hard to know which questions will work out well when you ask – if you could tell for sure, there'd probably be no question. :^)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's simply the surface of the counter (i.e., the top of the bar).